# Artillery NodeJS Cluster Performance Benchmarking Issue

Tags: node.js, artillery

I am using Artillery.IO with NodeJS to measure performance. NodeJS is running at my localhost and I am also running Artillery from same machine.

When I run Artillery with this script.

```
{
  "config": {
      "target": "http://localhost:3000/",
      "phases": [
          {
             "duration": 10,
             "arrivalRate": 2
          }
      ]
  },
  "scenarios": [
    {
       "flow": [
           {"get": {"url": "/"}}
       ]
    }
  ]
}
```

CASE 1:  NodeJS running with single cluster.

RESULT :
  ==============================

Scenarios launched:  20

Scenarios completed: 20

Requests completed:  20

RPS sent: 2

Request latency:

```
min: 1.1

max: 4.6

median: 1.2

p95: 3.3

p99: 4.6
```

Scenario counts:

```
0: 20 (100%)
```

Codes:

```
404: 20
```

==============================

CASE 2 : NodeJS running with 4 clusters.

RESULT :
  =============================

Scenarios launched:  20

Scenarios completed: 20

Requests completed:  20

RPS sent: 2

Request latency:

```
min: 1.2

max: 4.7

median: 1.4

p95: 3.2

p99: 4.7
```

Scenario counts:

```
0: 20 (100%)
```

Codes:

```
404: 20
```

==========================

My Node Server.js code is :

```
var http    = require('http');
var express = require('express');
var os = require('os');
var app     = express();
var server  = http.createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

app.get('/', function(req, res,next) {
    for(let i = 0; i < 10000000000; i++) {

    }
    console.log("Get Request received");
    res.send(new Date());
});

server.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log("Server is running in Port 3000");
});
```

My Question is why there is no improvement when I run NodeJS in cluster mode ?

Does it have to do something with the fact that both NodeJS and Artillery running on same system or It is server.js code that is not correctly written to measure performance.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in your YML file, "target" must be "http://localhost:3000" (without the trailing '/').

That's why you are receiving HTTP 404 (NOT FOUND) instead of HTTP 200 (OK)

Please update your YML as follows and rerun your test:

```
{
  "config": {
      "target": "http://localhost:3000",
      "phases": [
          {
             "duration": 10,
             "arrivalRate": 2
          }
      ]
  },
  "scenarios": [
    {
       "flow": [
           {"get": {"url": "/"}}
       ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Here you have my results:

**Single Cluster**

```
All virtual users finished
Summary report @ 20:26:36(+0000) 2018-05-31
  Scenarios launched:  20
  Scenarios completed: 6
  Requests completed:  6
  RPS sent: 0.15
  Request latency:
    min: 20756.8
    max: 115390.2
    median: 68364.2
    p95: 115390.2
    p99: 115390.2
  Scenario counts:
    0: 20 (100%)
  Codes:
    200: 6
  Errors:
    ESOCKETTIMEDOUT: 14
```

**#4 Cluster**

```
All virtual users finished
Summary report @ 20:22:09(+0000) 2018-05-31
  Scenarios launched:  20
  Scenarios completed: 4
  Requests completed:  4
  RPS sent: 0.15
  Request latency:
    min: 81288.9
    max: 83085.9
    median: 82870.6
    p95: 83085.9
    p99: 83085.9
  Scenario counts:
    0: 20 (100%)
  Codes:
    200: 4
  Errors:
    ESOCKETTIMEDOUT: 16
```

Note that in both scenarios, Codes are 200 (OK)

About your questions:

**My Question is why there is no improvement when I run NodeJS in cluster mode?**

Is not mandatory, unless your code splits the workload into several pieces that can run all together at the same time and then compose the deliverable at the end, you won't obtain a faster result. Performance is related to CPU speed and Throughput is related to the number of CPUs + CPU speed. 
(They are two different topics).

**Does it have to do something with the fact that both NodeJS and Artillery running on same system?**

No, Artillery has no impact. Look at the following pics, the only process that is CPU bound is your node server code (arti.js).

**Single Cluster**

[image: Single Cluster - Top]

## 4 Cluster

[image: #4 Cluster - Top]

**or It is server.js code that is not correctly written to measure performance?**

Exactly, partially answered before. Your code will run degraded if the number of node servers is greater than the available CPUs or vCPUs. And it's because your code is basically single-threaded code.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

This is because your artillery config is setup to run for 10 seconds total.
Once 10 seconds passes, the artillery script will exit, even though it has not yet received responses from in flight requests.

Your results show that all requests responded with 404, which is what artillery will default to when it exits before receiving responses to in flight requests.

Your server code is fine, and takes a long time to respond as you might expect. On my laptop, it's about 10 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I am getting different response time. Below is my yml code.

```
config:
  target: "http://localhost:3000"
  phases:
    - duration: 10
      arrivalRate: 10
scenarios:
  - flow:
    - get:
        url: "/"
```

**Response Time**

**CASE 1**

Report @ 12:29:38(+0530) 2018-06-05

```
Scenarios launched:  0
  Scenarios completed: 1
  Requests completed:  1
  RPS sent: NaN
  Request latency:
    min: 110658.5
    max: 110658.5
    median: 110658.5
    p95: 110658.5
    p99: 110658.5
  Codes:
    200: 1
```

**CASE 2**

All virtual users finished
Summary report @ 12:29:48(+0530) 2018-06-05

```
Scenarios launched:  100
  Scenarios completed: 10
  Requests completed:  10
  RPS sent: 0.77
  Request latency:
    min: 11300.8
    max: 110658.5
    median: 60775.7
    p95: 110658.5
    p99: 110658.5
  Scenario counts:
    0: 100 (100%)
  Codes:
    200: 10
  Errors:
    ESOCKETTIMEDOUT: 90
```